# Changing Div oppacity on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

First off, please don't yell at me for asking this question. I know there is already a million topics on this, and sadly I have read through them all and I STILL can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I created just a simple site to try understand how this works so that I can implement it on a more complex site.

I am just using one of the many scripts I have found and tried. All of them didn't have any effect.

The HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html>

<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.queness.com/js/bsa.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">



 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

  var colordivs = $('#fade div');

  $(document).scroll(function(e) {
      var scrollPercent = ($(window).scrollTop() / $('#fade').outerHeight()) * 100;

      if (scrollPercent > 0) {
          if (scrollPercent < 33) {
              var opacity = 1 - (scrollPercent / 33);
              $(colordivs[0]).css('opacity', opacity);
          }
          else if (scrollPercent > 66) {
              var opacity = 1 - (scrollPercent / 100);
              $(colordivs[0]).css('opacity', 0);
              $(colordivs[1]).css('opacity', 0);
              $(colordivs[2]).css('opacity', opacity);
          }
          else if (scrollPercent > 33) {
              var opacity = 1 - (scrollPercent / 66);
              $(colordivs[0]).css('opacity', 0);
              $(colordivs[1]).css('opacity', opacity);
          }
      }
  });

  });



</script>       
 </head>

 <body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="fade">
    </div>  
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.container {
height: 6000px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;

}
#fade {
background-image: url("skyline.png");
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden:
}
```

So I guess my first question is do I have everything? Am I missing a jquery script or something. and second does it matter where the css file is as along as its linked correctly in the html file? Like I said, I don't completely understand how the changing opacity works if it has anything to do with the css file.

I understand HTML and CSS completely and I understand what is going on in the script just fine, I just can't figure out why they aren't talking with each other and causing a change.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  var colordivs = $('#fade div');
```

to

```
  var colordivs = $('#fade');
```